# How to prove that homomorphism from field to ring is injective or zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Abstract Algebra ring homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36784/abstract-algebra-ring-homomorphism)

$f:K\rightarrow R$ is a homomorphism from field to ring. To prove is that it is injective or zero.

Comment: Hint: the kernel of $f$ is an ideal of $K.$

Comment: I am having a hard time believing this is not a duplicate, but I can't find one :/

Comment: @rschwieb - I agree. I'm having that deja vu feeling, but cannot locate where.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A ring homomorphism $f: R \to R'$ is injective if and only if [its kernel is $\{0\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167400/ring-map-one-to-one-kernel-proof)

Also, the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal.

Now let $f: K \to R$ be a ring homomorphism from a field into a ring. The only ideals in a field $K$ are $\{0\}$ and $K$ itself. Hence $f$ can either have kernel $\{0\}$ or $K$ itself. In the former case, $f$ is injective, in the latter case it is the zero map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but actually the fact that zero set and K are the only ideals also has to be proven

Comment: @starovoitovs It sure does : )

Comment: [Here ya go](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167400/ring-map-one-to-one-kernel-proof) @nakajuice

Answer (score 12):

$f(x)=f(y) \iff f(x)-f(y)=0 \overset{f\text{ hom.}}{\iff} f(x-y)=0$.

If there are $x\ne y$ with this property (ie., $f$ is not injective), then multply it by $f\left(\displaystyle\frac1{x-y}\right)$ and conclude that $f(s)=0$ for all $s\in K$, using the fact that $f$ is homomorphism, i.e. behaves friendly with the ring operations and that $s=1\cdot s$.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew's hint in the comments to your question is a good way to look at it, especially since it generalizes to simple rings (rings with exactly two ideals, both of them trivial).

So, you can prove the statement: If $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a homomorphism of rings, and $R$ is a simple ring, then $f$ is injective.

This of course covers fields as a special case. Moreover, it is best looked at with Andrew's hint: "Show $\ker(f)$ is an ideal of $R$."