# How to formally prove that $\Bbb Q[i]$ is not isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to prove that $\Bbb Q[i]$ is not isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb R$. We know that the ring $\Bbb Q[i]$ is actually a field. So if it is isomorphic to some subring of $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R$ then becomes an extension of $\Bbb Q[i].$ So do we just prove that there is no ring homomorphism from $\Bbb Q[i]$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hint: Assume there was a monomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[i] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, you could ask what is $\phi(i) \in \mathbb{R}$. Whichever element $x$ you pick for that, note that $x^2 = \phi(i)^2 = \phi(i^2) = \phi(-1) = -1$. Now you only have to think about why that last equality holds, and what that tells you about your possible choices for $x$.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Firstly, may I ask why should we prove there is no injective homomorphism from $\Bbb Q[i]$ to $\Bbb R$? Shouldn't we prove there is no ring homomorphism at all?

Comment: @Y.X. an injective homomorphism is an isomorphism with a subring.

Comment: A ring homomorphism from a field to a ring is always an injection. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232955/how-to-prove-that-homomorphism-from-field-to-ring-is-injective-or-zero (Assuming the ring has $1\ne 0$ and that ring homomorphisms preserve unity.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The reason for $\phi(-1)=-1$ is that $\phi(-1+1)=\phi(-1)+\phi(1)=\phi(-1)+1=0.$ And then we have shown that that $x \in \Bbb R$ must have square -1. Such an $x$ does not exist in $\Bbb R$ at all. Am I correct?

Comment: @Y.X. Yes, that is correct. A related argument is that any subring of R has an order compatible with the field operations (induced by the ordering on R) but Q[i] has no such ordering since $i^2 = -1 < 0$ but any square is always positive by a case analysis ($-\times - = +\times + = +)$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is isomorphic to a subring of $\mathbb{R}$, and call the isomorphism from the former to the latter, $\varphi$.

Consider $\varphi(i^2 + 1) = \varphi(i^2) + \varphi(1) = [\varphi(i)]^2 + 1$, where the first equality follows because homomorphisms respect addition, and the second follows because homomorphisms respect multiplication (and because $1$ is mapped to $1$, an exercise I presume you have seen or completed).

And so now we have $[\varphi(i)]^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

But we can evaluate the earlier expression in a different way: $\varphi(i^2 + 1) = \varphi(0) = 0$, where the first equality follows because $i^2 + 1 = 0$, and the second equality follows because $0$ is mapped to $0$ (again, an exercise I presume you have seen or completed).

Put together, we have: $[\varphi(i)]^2 + 1 = 0$, for some real number $\varphi(i)$. But this is problematic, since it would mean we could square the real number $\varphi(i)$ and get $-1$. Contradiction, since no real number can be squared to yield $-1$. So our supposition was wrong, and no such isomorphism exists.