# Every homomorphism $\varphi : F \to R$ from a field $F$ to a nonzero ring $R$ is injective: proof details in Artin

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

In Artin's Algebra the statement in the title is introduced as a corollary of the following:

> The only ideals of a field are the zero ideal and the unit ideal.   $\star$

The proof of the statement in the title then goes as following:

> The kernel of $\varphi$ is an ideal of $F$. So according to $\star$, the kernel is either $(0)$ or $(1)$. If $\ker \varphi$ were the unit ideal $(1)$, $\varphi$ would be the zero map. **But the zero map isn't a homomorphism when $R$ isn't the zero ring**. Therefore $\ker \varphi = (0),$ and $\varphi$ is injective.

Now $R$ sure isn't the zero ring, but the zero ring is still embedded in $R$. Suppose $\varphi$ is the zero map, then

$$
\varphi(a + b) = 0 = 0 + 0 = \varphi(a) + \varphi(b)\\ 
\varphi(ab) = 0 = 0 \cdot 0 = \varphi(a)\varphi(b) \\
\varphi(1_R) = 0 = 1,
$$

so $\varphi$ is a homomorphism from $F$ to $R$ (although it doesn't hit anything except $0$ in $R$).

So is the statement in bold technically incorrect, or am I missing something? [Other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232955/how-to-prove-that-homomorphism-from-field-to-ring-is-injective-or-zero) on this topic indicate that other authors like to phrase the original statement as "*$\varphi$ is injective **or** the zero map"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the last claim which fails:
$$\varphi(1_R) = 0 \neq  1$$

Note that if $R$ is a ring and $0=1$, then $R$ is the zero ring.

Indeed, for all $x \in R$ we have
$$x=x \cdot 1=x \cdot 0=0$$

Comment: Thank you! So the last claim fails really because any subring is supposed to inherit 1 from the ring?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy The last claim fails because in an unitary ring, unless the ring is trivial, $1 \neq 0$. And part of the definition of ring homomorphism is $\phi(1)=1$.