# Are there zero morphisms in the category of fields?

Tags: field-theory, category-theory

A homomorphism between fields is either injective or zero (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232955/how-to-prove-that-homomorphism-from-field-to-ring-is-injective-or-zero)). Hence the category of fields should(?) have zero morphisms, but it seems like when talking about the category of fields, people say every morphism is a monomorphism.

Is the category of fields defined in a way that forbids zero morphisms?

Comment: Yes, it's defined as a subcategory of unital rings, rather than a subcategory of rings without unit. Morphisms of unital rings must preserve the unit, and thus aren't zero.